# SQL Select Distinct but include separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Example Data from table Vehicle

```
ID     BODY TYPE        Litre
1      AAA              1.5
2      BBB; CCC         1.9
3      DDD              1.9
4      EEE; FFF; GGG    1.8
5      GGG              1.8
```

I need a Select Distinct statement that will bring the following result into a query so we are selecting all unique values but also splitting by ; as well.

```
BODY TYPE
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
```

I have looked at similar questions that contain various functions but I would like the result viewable as a **query**. I have tried adapting the suggestion below to my scenario

Comment: You really shouldn't store the data like that if you can possibly help it.

Comment: Its a set vehicle index - trust me, i wouldn't if it were my choice but it needs to be like this unfortunately :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really store your data in a normalised form. That said, try this

```
;with c as (
    select bodytype, 0 as start, CHARINDEX(';', bodytype) as sep 
    from Vehicle
    where litre=1.9 
    union all
    select bodytype, sep, CHARINDEX(';', bodytype, sep+1) from c
    where sep>0

)
    select distinct LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(bodytype,start+1,chars))) as [BodyType]
    from
    (
        select *, Case sep when 0 then LEN(bodytype) else sep-start-1 end as chars
        from c
    ) v
```

Comment: This is looking more promising, I guess I can still add a where by clause in here ?

Comment: e.g. where litre = 1.9

Comment: Thanks, looks good so far in SQL server - just hope it works from an ASP page now

Comment: The result says no column name - if i wanted to write the result back in ASP, i would usually write response.write recordset2.fields("Body Type") or equivalent, do we need a column name ?

Comment: or what do I use in the response.write

Comment: @EmmaLees-Smith I've given it a bodytype column name

Answer (score 5):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (string VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
('AAA'),          
('BBB; CCC'),     
('DDD'),           
('EEE; FFF; GGG'), 
('GGG')    

SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)'))
FROM (
    SELECT ID = CAST ('<t>' + REPLACE(string, ';', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM @temp
) r 
CROSS APPLY ID.nodes ('/t') t(c)
```

Output -

```
----------
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. What is t.c.value ? why is there a full stop there ? I don't want to create any separate tables, I just need a simple select statement that I can use on my ASP pages.

Comment: this is just an extract from the database - there are 1000's of rows, i don't understand why we are inserting them into @temp table and how this could be done with 1000's rows.

Comment: @EmmaLees-Smith the `@temp` table is your vehicle table. This is just an example

Comment: @devart While this perhaps looks neater, even on a small sample it seems to perform significantly worse than the CTE. Thoughts?

Comment: @podiluska if I am not confusing anything, functionality for working with `XML` is not native to `SQL Server` and is loaded from external libraries. That's why working with large amounts of data with the help of XML is not as effective as working with them with the help of `CTE`. As for me, I use `XML` only if I'm sure that there is not much data.